# How to run a specific Haskell code in Windows?

Tags: haskell

I had installed Haskell compiler.

I use CMD, I type `ghci` and I getting the Haskell prompt `Prelude>`

All the following examples works:

`Prelude> "Hello, World!"
"Hello, World!"`

or

`Prelude> let fac n = if n == 0 then 1 else n * fac (n-1)
 Prelude> fac 42
1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000`

I'm trying to run this code:

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes
binom n k = product [p^(f n p - f k p - f (n - k) p) |
                     p <- takeWhile (<= n) primes] where
  f 0 _ = 0
  f m p = div m p + f (div m p) p
```

taken from: https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-efficient-algorithms-to-compute-nCr

For using `Data.Numbers.Primes` I had installed primes-0.2.1.0.tar.gz package.

When I enter in the prompt `Prelude>` the following:

```
import Data.Numbers.Primes
```

I get this prompt `Prelude Data.Numbers.Primes>`

I created a file named `binom.hs` and run:

```
ghc -o binom binom.hs
```

I get the following error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( binom.hs, binom.o )

binom.hs:1:1: error:
    The IO action `main' is not defined in module `Main'
  |
1 | import Data.Numbers.Primes
  | ^
```

I tried to enter all the command in prompt `Prelude Data.Numbers.Primes>`

```
binom n k = product [p^(f n p - f k p - f (n - k) p) | p <- takeWhile (<= n) primes] where f 0 _ = 0 f m p = div m p + f (div m p) p
```

but I get an error:

```
<interactive>:3:108: error: parse error on input `='
```

How do I solve this issue and run this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is really clear. As in many programming languages, you need a function `main` of type `IO ()` defined in your program for it to compile into an executable.

```hs
main = print $binom 42 2
```

Comment: One question at a time please.